# Finding closest pair of points from one array to another

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

I have two arrays of points v and v1. Need to find the closest pair from array v for each point in array v1. I came out with the three following methods to calculate the indices and distances for each points of v1. Real dataset can have 100s of millions of rows.

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial import distance 
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import time


np.random.seed(0)
n = 6
m=15
v = np.random.rand(n, 2) # sluice gate mid points
v1 = np.random.rand(m, 2) #mesh points

# naive python 
tic = time.time()
def closest_node(node, nodes): # distance of a mesh node from sluice gate nodes
    nodes = np.asarray(nodes)
    d = np.sum((nodes - node)**2, axis=1)
    distance=np.sqrt(d).min()
    return [np.argmin(d)+1,distance]

table=[]
for j in range(len(v1)):
    print(j+1, closest_node(v1[j],v)) # comment out for larger arrary
    table.append({'Node':j+1, 'nearest sluice(1-6)':closest_node(v1[j],v)[0],'distance':closest_node(v1[j],v)[1] })
    df1=pd.DataFrame(table)    

toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic)    

# using kdtree module
tic = time.time()

kdtree = KDTree(v)
table=[]
for j in range(len(v1)):
    
 d, i = kdtree.query(v1[j])
 #node number /j+1, nearest sluice(1-6)/i, distance/d
 print("closest point:  ",j+1, i+1, d,v1[j])
 table.append({'Node':j+1, 'nearest sluice(1-6)':i+1,'distance':d})
 df2=pd.DataFrame(table)

toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic) 

# using cdist module
tic = time.time()  
def closest_node(node, nodes): # distance of a mesh node from sluice gate nodes
    d= cdist([node], nodes, 'euclidean').min()
    closest_index = distance.cdist([node], nodes).argmin()
    return closest_index+1, d
table=[] 
for j in range(len(v1)):
    print(j+1, closest_node(v1[j],v))    
    table.append({'Node':j+1, 'nearest sluice(1-6)':closest_node(v1[j],v)[0],'distance':closest_node(v1[j],v)[1] })
    df3=pd.DataFrame(table)   
    
toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic) 
#check if all dfs results are equal
dfs=[df1,df2,df3]
all(x.equals(dfs[0]) for x in dfs)
```

Please let me know what are other unique ways to solve this problem.

Comment: Finding nearest point in a sorted array is `O(log n)` and sorting two array is `O(n log n)`. So overall complexity is  `2nlog n + nlog n ~ O(nlogn)`. Do you want to find a linear solution?

Comment: yes, a linear solution will be good.

Comment: Closest pair algorithm for comparing points from 2 different arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077948/closest-pair-algorithm-for-comparing-points-from-2-different-arrays

Comment: give FAISS a try - http://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/wiki

Comment: store your vectors in [Pinecone and query](https://www.pinecone.io/docs/quickstart/), it uses approximate nearest neighbors (ANN) search, which is much faster. Faiss mentioned above uses ANN algos too, if you'd rather use Faiss there's a good set of articles explaining how on the Pinecone website too, like [this one](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/faiss-tutorial/)